# I am new in flutter firebase. I want to print total value of the field named amount of each firebase document

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

There is a field named Amount inside the document under a collection called Use of Fund. Now I want to add the value of the field named amount of each document
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DkF8A.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First Step:** Get the documents from the collection:

```
final result = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Use of Fund').get();
```

**Second Step:** Define a variable to hold the result and start it with 0:

```
double totalAmount = 0;
```

**Third Step:** Loop on the `docs` inside the `result` and add the amount of each `doc`:

```
for (var doc in result.docs){
    totalAmount += doc['amount'];
}
```

**That's It!**

Comment: thank you @Moaz El-sawaf but i got this error "Expected a value of type 'String', but got one of type '_Future<dynamic>'"

Comment: Can you please share the code snippet?

Comment: my code is here  https://prnt.sc/G-r5P7K-Wlub

Comment: The problem is that you are trying to use the output of the function directly inside the `Text` widget while it is taking time to get the value, so you have to wait before rendering the `Text` widget until you get the value. You can use `FutureBuilder` to get the data with a loading and validation logic. Check out this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Pp3zoNDGZUI

Comment: You are always welcome, I would be glad if you accepted the answer.

Comment: I didn't know how to accept the answer, so it was too late